# Nginx 404 for some clients

Tags: nginx

Got nginx installed as proxy (http on remote host)

Few clients (host-tracker, NL and UA) geting 404 eror (not all, dns cache updated like 5-6 days ago).

```
37.143.10.29  domain 200 - "GET /business/2013-1/index.html HTTP/1.1"
85.17.162.105 domain 404 - "GET /business/2013-1/index.html HTTP/1.1"
```

Backend not logging error only nginx
Somethings wrong in config or what, i cant find reason.

Comment: So what does the error log say?

Comment: And what about some configs? Did you try something like _load balancing_, _rate limiting_ or the likes?

Comment: there no any other errors, only this one

Comment: ive not triyed "load balancing, rate limiting or the likes" but there only few domains

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Problem was that when I asked my hosting provider to update the A-records to my new hosting, he only changed the IPv4 A-records, forgot to update the IPv6 AAAA-records.

Most clients still connect through IPv4 by default, but some already connect through IPv6.

Solutions:

- Update the AAAA-records
- Remove the AAAA-records so there is a fallback to IPv4